# How to implement long-running transactions over a web service, like unit of work

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, transactions, unit-of-work

I'm designing a web service and a desktop client application that uses the web service. The interface has a requirement that you need to be able to perform multiple operations and commit them all at once. The operations are basic CRUD operations (create, read, update, delete).

Here's a rough, and Car-ified example of what the workflow would be:

[image: Rough idea of service calls]

The problem is that the service calls could be spread out over time. I originally had created a REST web service, but REST by definition shouldn't be transactional. The interface has to be able to commit all operations to the database in one go (upon a Save button click).

**Edit:** An important stipulation is that given the example above, a Car must exist in the database on the server in order to add seats to it. Within a transaction, that car should only be available to the person (session) who is working within that transaction. That limits the ability to send all the operations to the web service at one time at the end of the workflow.

The options I have considered so far are:

**1)** Implement distributed transactions using SOAP (WCF) and only commit when Save is clicked on the GUI. Is this possible/a good idea for longer transaction lifetimes?

**2)** Create a unit of work 'service' that takes operations and executes them all within one transaction on the server.

My question is, is **1)** possible, or a good/bad idea? Is **2)** a good idea, and are there any patterns/tools for implementing this across a web service (REST or SOAP)? Or is there a different way to handle this problem?

Comment: I have written WCF REST Service which take almost 30+ objects and all CRUD operation is done in one transaction. There is no harm in doing so.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added a stipulation to clarify why that won't work in my case. It's because in order to add seats to a car, the car must exist in the database for a user's session. However, that whole session must be rolled back if creating the seats fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this:

```
POST /unit-of-work 
   create with response 200
POST /car
   create with response 202
POST /seat
   create with response 202
etc.
PUT /unit-of-work
   set "execute" bit, or somesuch
```

In this case, car, seat, etc have the unit-of-work specified when they're posted. When the unit-of-work is updated to be "done", all the items are executed.

Another approach would be:

```
POST /car
   create with response 202
POST /seat
   create with response 202
etc.
POST /unit-of-work response 200
```

In this case, car, seat, etc have a bit set saying they're not created yet. The unit-of-work should specify what resources belong to it, and then the back end can flip the bit on the other resources so they're created.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Sorry for the missing details, but I've added a stipulation that the Car must exist in the database for that user's session/transaction in order to add seats to the it. That means your second approach may be close to what I'm looking for. You could create the entities in the database but have them only available if queried with some sort of session token or unit-of-work token.

Comment: However, I was hoping SOAP distributed transactions would be able to take care of that for me. Do you happen to know if a SOAP transaction can be used for this sort of thing?

Comment: I would imagine so, yeah. I'm not really that well-versed on SOAP.

Comment: Based on some research I've done so far, long-running transactions in soap are not what they are designed for and to implement something like this, you would have to use compensation to update any changes made during a session, but I'm still looking into it.